# How to DROP and CREATE a table in SQL Server 2016 Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will drop a table and then create a new table with the same name.

However, when I right clicked on the table and did `Script Table as ... DROP and CREATE To ... New Query Editor Window` and then copied the script into a blank stored procedure, it wouldn't let me create the procedure because

> There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database

What should I do?

NOTE: the new table will not be the same structure as the old table. I make some transformations using other stored procedures to the table, so at the end, I want to drop it and create from scratch.

Here is the actual script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDropAndCreate]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.MyTable','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Col1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col6] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col7] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col9] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Col10] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    )
    GO
END
```

Here is the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDropAndCreate, Line 17 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MyTable'
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 35
>   There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 156
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Comment: 1) post the script 2) post the actual error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `GO` after the `DROP TABLE` statement to separate the batches.

This won’t work for a procedure though. Instead uses exists when sys objects.

```
If exists(select 1 from sys.objects where name = 'mytable')
drop mytable
```

Comment: You can't have `GO` within a Stored Procedure, and everything between  `BEGIN` and `END` is the Stored Procedure body

Comment: That’s correct I overlooked it was in a procedure. Fixed for a proc @Red Good eye

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `GO` that is within the `BEGIN` and `END` block. `GO` is a batch separator which is like telling the block to execute before it's even ended.  Check out this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180279/when-do-i-need-to-use-begin-end-blocks-and-the-go-keyword-in-sql-server) for more info.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDropAndCreate]
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.MyTable','U') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
   (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Col1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col5] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col6] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col7] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col9] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col10] [nvarchar](50) NULL
   )    
END
```